# How to convert multiple Json responses into one dataframe in python

Tags: python, json, pandas, json-normalize, pandas-explode

I need to create a dataframe for the output generated from the API response `response.json()` my output looks like this:

```
{'output':[[2,3,4]]}
{'output':[[6,3,7]]}
```

I have tried to normalize it by using this code:

```
pd.json_normalize(response.json())
```

but the result I got is:

```
     output
0 [[2,3,4]]
     output
0 [[6,3,7]]
```

it seems that is creating multiple dataframe and I don't know how to handle it, any ideas?

Many thanks!

This is what I am looking for

```
   output
0 [2,3,4]
1 [6,3,7]
```

Comment: Adjust the code to store all the responses in a list: `data = [{'output':[[2,3,4]]}, {'output':[[6,3,7]]}]` and then `df = pd.DataFrame(data).explode('output').explode('output')` is the simplest option. `.explode` is used twice because one is needed for each level of `[[...]]`.

Comment: you can flatten the dictionaries `pd.DataFrame({'output': [j for i in data['output'] for j in i]})`

Comment: thank, unfortunately it will still return multiple dataframe and it will split to row each element on each list.

Answer (score 0):

Your response is indeed two separate JSON entities. You can do the following to merge it into 1 dataframe:

```
pd.concat(pd.json_normalize(response.json()))
```

That being said, your json_normalize probably isn't going to generate the dataframe in a way that you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not apply to my case, I got this error: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"